# Smart Home & Touch Controls: visual cards never update after successful Execute commands

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home

According to the documentation, visual assistants and the Google Home app display graphical interfaces for certain traits without any development work.

https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create#touch-controls

However, I have implemented a smart home action which uses the brightness trait to dim and brighten a users lights. I am succesfully reporting the states of the users devices to Home Graph after the original sync and every execute request but the visual display never seems to update after a successful Execute command.

[image]

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Updating of touch controls is dependent on a successful implementation of the report state feature. I would recommend using the [Report State Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/report-state#deploy-report-state-dashboard) tool to validate that your calls to the HomeGraph API are successfully making it all the way to update the expected device state.

If you are able to validate the HomeGraph updates using this tool but are still not seeing UI updates, please [file an issue](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/support).